# Compound literals for scalar types

Tags: c, compound-literals

Since `c99` compound literals can be used to e.g. initialize pointers:

```
int *p = (int []) {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

while this is usually used for `struct`s it can be used to initialize anonymous arrays as well (see example). But if I understood this correctly initializing a scalar pointer like this:

```
int *p = &(int) {4};
```

is also valid. What I find confusing is the statement on the `gcc` site that “Compound literals for scalar types and union types are also allowed, but then the compound literal is equivalent to a cast.” Do they simply mean that using the address-of operator `&` in front of an anonymous scalar is a form of casting?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition a compound literal does not consist of `&` address-of operator. From N1570 `6.5.2.5/p3` *Compound literals*:

> A postfix expression that consists of a parenthesized type name
>   followed by a brace-enclosed list of initializers is a *compound
>   literal*.

Now, their statement:

> Compound literals for scalar types and union types are also allowed,
>   but then the compound literal is equivalent to a cast.

is rather wrong if I am reading it correctly. The fundamental difference between compound literal and cast operator is that the former is a *lvalue*, as by N1570 `6.5.2.5/p4` (emphasis mine):

> Otherwise (when the type name specifies an object type), the type of
>   the compound literal is that specified by the type name. In either
>   case, the **result is an lvalue**.

while the latter is not, `6.5.4/p5` *Cast operators* (emphasis mine):

> Preceding an expression by a parenthesized type name converts the
>   value of the expression to the named type. This construction is called
>   a cast<sup>.104)</sup>
>
> 104) A cast **does not yield an lvalue**. Thus, a cast to a qualified type
>   has the same effect as a cast to theunqualified version of the type.

Comment: "The fundamental difference between compound literal and cast operator is that the latter is a lvalue [...]". Shouldn't this be "the former"?

Comment: Ok, so there is nothing special about using compound literals to initialize scalar pointers?

Comment: @brauner: No, It's analogous to as you initialize anonymous array with it.